# Copy and Add Elements by jQuery in Client Side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is My Default.aspx:

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="Target">
    <label>
        First Object</label>
    <input title="firstnum" />
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />
</div>
<asp:Button ID="AddNewbtn" runat="server" Text="New One" />
</form>
</body>
```

I need a jQuery Script to Copy All Elements in `<div class="Target" >` and Add them in bottom of Target div when I press AddNewbtn Button, How Can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is better

```
$("#AddNewbtn").click(function(){
$(".Target:first").clone().insertAfter('.Target:last');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), and event listener [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
$("#AddNewbtn").click(function(){
    $(".Target:first").clone().insertAfter('.Target');
});
```

Comment: Slight issue with this is that for each progressive click you'll end up with click*2 divs. You need a mechanism to select the first template div only.

Comment: @Martin this not work correctly, at first time copy-paste one item, next copy and paste both of them and go on ascending, also this script copy elements by value, for ex if I type anything in input element, by click AddNewbtn values also copied .